# How to disable the automatic generation of DslValidator in Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext, mwe

I need to disable the automatic generation of a DslValidator class (extends AbstractDslValidator) by the MWE2. I use my own DslValidator xtend class and I have to delete it after every mwe2 workflow run. How can this be achieved? Thank you!

Comment: can you give more context and usecase. e.g why dont you change to class to inherit from your class. you cannot disable it. you would need a custom fragment to do so. you can also change to have a class in src-gen only with `validator = {generateStub = false}` but i have doubts it is what you want.

Comment: inheritation worked, i somehow thought the automatic generation would alter that construct, thank you!

Comment: the class is generate once only so that you can customize it / implement checks